# Change all <p> elements with a class to <code>

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementsbyclassname

This is working fine using the `document.getElementsByID`, but how do you change all the `p` tags with a `prgrph` class to `code` so that instead of `<p class="prgrph"></p>` there will be `<code class="prgrph"></code>`?

```
var b = document.querySelectorAll('p'); 

for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  b[i].setAttribute('id', 'prgrph');
}
```

But this is not working:

```
function changeTagName(el, newTagName) {
  var n = document.createElement(newTagName);
  var attr = el.attributes;
  for (var i = 0, len = attr.length; i < len; ++i) {
    n.setAttribute(attr[i].name, attr[i].value);
  }
  n.innerHTML = el.innerHTML;
  el.parentNode.replaceChild(n, el);
}

changeTagName(document.getElementsByClassName('prgrph'), 'code');
```

I tried to use `document.getElementsByClassName` and it's giving me error on the `attr.length`:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] with relevant HTML

Comment: There is no `HTMLCollection#attributes` property, so getting it's length will likely not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IDs need to be unique and you likely want to change the `P` tags one by one

I am not sure why you first loop over the `P` tags and then loop again; the first loop is not really needed if the second loop selects the `P` tag instead of the class

```js
var b = document.querySelectorAll('p');

for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  b[i].classList.add('prgrph');
}

function changeTagName(el, newTagName) {
  var n = document.createElement(newTagName);
  var attr = el.attributes;
  for (var i = 0, len = attr.length; i < len; ++i) {
    n.setAttribute(attr[i].name, attr[i].value);
  }
  n.innerHTML = el.innerHTML;
  el.parentNode.replaceChild(n, el);
}

document.querySelectorAll(".prgrph").forEach(function(p) { // not IE
  changeTagName(p, 'code');
})
```

```css
code {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<p data-attr="one">Paragraph 1</p>
<p data-attr="two">Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
```

Comment: See updated comment - the first loop might not be necessary dependent on your needs